# Debezium Connector Sends Mostly Zeros When Updating Row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

From the [documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html) for the Oracle Debezium Connector it seems that when an update is performed on a row it should send a Kafka message with all of the data for the state of the row before the update and all of the data for the state of the row after the update. However, I am getting zeros in almost all of the fields, except the field that was updated and one other field that has a unique constraint, but which is not used by Debezium as the key. The key used by Debezium is a combination of four fields, which together are unique. Here is how I created the connector. How can I get Debezium to give me data for all of the fields, not just the one that was updated, or is this not possible?

```
{
    "name": "bom-tables",
    "config": {
        "name": "bom-tables",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
        "database.server.name": "fake.example.com",
        "database.hostname": "fake2.example.com",
        "snapshot.mode": "initial",
        "database.port": "1521",
        "database.user": "XSTRM",
        "database.password": "FAKE_PASS",
        "database.dbname": "FAKE_DBNAME",
        "database.out.server.name": "DBZXOUT",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
        "database.tablename.case.insensitive": "true",
        "database.oracle.version": "11",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "table.whitelist": "XXX,YYY",
        "errors.log.enable": "true"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you follow the steps of preparing database? https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html#_preparing_the_database

Comment: Unfortunately I did not set up Debezium or the Oracle database.